# Splitting GitHub releases

Tags: github

I just migrated an old project from an own Subversion/Trac infrastructure to GitHub

https://github.com/matteocorti/nagios_plugins

The repository contains one directory for each plugin I wrote. Each plugin is standalone and has an own version number (but the source code is in the same repository).

When I release a new plugin version I would like to have a release with just the corresponding folder (e.g., https://github.com/matteocorti/nagios_plugins/tree/master/check_updates)

Is there a way with the GitHub release feature to select which part of a repository contains the software to be released?

Another option would be to split the whole and have a repository for each plugin. This would imply that I will have to manually move all the issues/bugs and wiki pages.

**Edit**

It seems that the only solution would be to split the repository (a separate repository for each plugin).

How can I split a Git repository retaining the commit history?

Comment: you could alternatively look into git submodules; but personally I'd prefer multiple repositories here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that the only solution would be to split the repository (a separate repository for each plugin).

It is, but that does not migrate wiki pages and issues.

To split a git repo while keeping the history, see GitHub page "[Splitting a subfolder out into a new repository](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/)"

```
git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter \
 YOUR_FOLDER_NAME master
# Filter the master branch to your directory and remove empty commits
# Rewrite 48dc599c80e20527ed902928085e7861e6b3cbe6 (89/89)
# Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
```

> The repository now contains all the files that were in your subfolder.
>   Note that although all of your previous files have been removed, they still exist within the Git history. You can now push your new local repository to a new repository on GitHub.

Check also "[How to tear apart a repository: the Git way](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/04/tear-apart-repository-git-way/) "

Once you have one repo per plugin, you can still register them in your original repo, as [**git submodules**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

**Edit**

To push the subfolder to a new repository

```
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote add origin NEW_URL
git push origin master
```

Comment: Thanks, I added how to push the subdir to a new repository